# how to write service kind of function in React which can fetch then return data using input params of function

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am new bee to React and from angular background. I a trying to write reusable function which can process API calls using input(country code) and can return data to components. so that i can use that data as per my needs in side components.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
const APIService=function(countrycode){
let newsData=[];
fetch(process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL+'top-headlines? 
   country='+countrycode+'&apiKey='+process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY)
   .then((responce) =>{
  return responce.json()
}).then(data => {
  newsData=data;
  //Got data hear
  console.log(data);
 return newsData
}).catch(error=>{
  return(<div>Somethinhg went wrong. Sorry forinconvinance</div>)
})
}
export  default APIService;
```

and in side my component

```
import React from 'react';
import APIService from '../APIService/APIService';
export default class LatestNews extends React.Component {
constructor(){}

componentWillMount(){
//Not getting Data hear
console.log(APIService('us'))

}
}
```

I am getting 'undefined'. i knew i have 2 issues here. 
one is how to return data from APIService function
second is how to make component to wait until data comes.

i tried componentDidMount() as well. but not worked. Want to simplyfy the process, so dont want to put any JSX syntax in component to pass params in terms of props.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ApiManager.js

```
export class ApiManager extends Component {
static myInstance = null;

static getInstance() {  
    return new ApiManager();
}
async getMoviesFromApiAsync(countryCode) {
    try {
        let response = await fetch(
            'https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/callingcode/'+countryCode,
        );
        let responseJson = await response.json();
        return responseJson;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
}
}
export default ApiManager
```

FetchData.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import ApiManager from '../utils/ApiManager';
export default class FetchData extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        resultArr: []
    }
}

callApi() {
    //Call Api with parameter 91 as countryCode
    ApiManager.getInstance().getMoviesFromApiAsync(91).then((result) => {
        console.log('result from API ====>', result)
        this.setState({ resultArr: result });
    });
}
render() {
    return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
            <TouchableOpacity style={{ backgroundColor: 'green', padding: 20 }} onPress={() => this.callApi()}>
                <Text style={{ color: 'white' }}> Fetch Data </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <Text>{JSON.stringify(this.state.resultArr[0])}</Text>
        </View>
    )
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

APIService.js

```
export default class APIService {
static classInstance = null;
static getAPIServiceInstance() {
    if (APIService.classInstance === null) {
        APIService.classInstance = new APIService();
    }
    return this.classInstance;
}
callAPI(countrycode) {
    let newsData = [];
    fetch(process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL + 'top-headlines? 
   country = '+countrycode+' & apiKey='+process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY)
        .then((responce) => {
            return responce.json()
        }).then(data => {
            newsData = data;
            //Got data hear
            console.log(data);
            return newsData
        }).catch(error => {
            return (<div>Somethinhg went wrong. Sorry forinconvinance</div>)
        })
}
}
```

LatestNews.js

```
import React from 'react';
import APIService from '../APIService/APIService';
export default class LatestNews extends React.Component {
constructor(){}

componentWillMount(){
     var result= APIService.getAPIServiceInstance().callAPI('us')
    }
}
```

Comment: Your logic is almost nearer. but still failing. since we are checking (APIService.classInstance === null) , "return this.classInstance" is going to call APIService again but not along with callAPI() for second time. so that is just returning function. As I mentioned in callAPI() i am not able to throw return results to LatestNews component. again getting 'undefined' at LatestNews component. can you or any one please provide working fiddle with some public API... Eg: https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random